# How much extra CO2 is produced (in the EU) each year due to the introduction of manatory car headlights during daylight hours?

Tags: estimation, climate-science

Forcing drivers to keep their lights on during daylight hours may increase road safety, but there must be an environmental impact (not to mention a financial benefit to certain organisations).

I am interested in measuring this impact, specifically the extra $\mathrm{CO_2}$ that has been produced as a result of the legislation, but I'm unsure as how to undertake the required calculations.

Comment: Pick an average car and look up the power required for the headlights. Now multiply the duration of daylight and an estimated number of cars, and you have the amount of energy. Look up the energy content in the fuel so see how small a portion, headlights account for and find out how much CO2 that corresponds to the fuel usage.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about physics

Comment: This also isn't an EU rule as far as I know: I live in a country which is (still) part of the EU and it's not a rule here.

Answer (score 3):

(This should have been a comment but got too long for the comment box.)

That's not the only environmental cost associated with the change.  Consider a daytime accident caused by one driver who failed to see another, which could have been averted if both drivers had been using their headlights.  Now you have two vehicles which require replacement body panels, perhaps replacement mechanical parts, or perhaps will be totally scrapped and replaced with new vehicles.

What is the environmental impact of building a new car to replace one that should have had five or ten years of operational life remaining?  You have to subtract this avoided cost from the environmental cost of running the headlights.

Car headlights seem to draw [about 100 watts](http://hypertextbook.com/facts/2005/YatManTsui.shtml); dedicated "daytime running lights" may draw less, but that's a nice round number.   The construction cost for a car [seems to be](http://www.thetruthaboutcars.com/2009/08/cash-for-clunkers-the-environmental-cost-of-a-new-car/) about $10^{11}$ joules (given in the link as $10^8$ BTU).  So running the headlights for $10^9\rm\,s = 30\,years$ costs the same energy as building and driving a car.

As Steeven points out, 100 W is a tiny fraction of the operating power of a car.
Suppose you get 40 mpg and drive at 40 mph: your engine is consuming a gallon of gasoline per hour, an effective power of 27 kilowatts (modulo some factor-of-three corrections for efficiency).  Your 100 watt headlamp is a sub-1% correction.

If you want to offset the carbon footprint of having your headlights on, just drive one mile per hour slower.

Comment: To make it worse, the alternator is spinning all the time generating electricity.

Comment: A couple of other factors that could make daytime running lights have a net benefit: gasoline tanks sometimes rupture in accidents, and accidents significantly impede the flow of traffic, thereby making all the other drivers on the road suffer degraded gas mileage.